# Domainspoofing Prevention with exceptions

Tags: security, networking, dns, firewall, system-administration

I'm a sysadmin and I have to find a way to prevent domainspoofing with mails. Normally I'd do it with a mailflow-Rule in exchange onprem. The problem is, we have mail-newsletter, from where some people in our company send newsletter from to our co-workers. Some use chipmonkey, other use newsletter2go, etc. etc.

I know that you can use DKIM or DMARC, idk what is better or what you shouldn't use.

May you guys give me some tips how to do it, or how would you realize it?

Ty in advance!

- Filip

I tried it with a mailflow rule, but there are too many IP's that you would have to except.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/